# Python - Inner Functions, Closures, and Factory Functions - how to factor out?

Tags: python

I'm hoping a Python expert out there can offer some assistance on the confusion I'm experiencing currently with Inner Functions, Closures, and Factory Functions.  Upon looking for an implemented example of a General Hough Transform I found this:

https://github.com/vmonaco/general-hough/blob/master/src/GeneralHough.py

I'd like to translate this into C++ and it seems the first step is to factor out the inner function in general_hough_closure():

```
def general_hough_closure(reference_image):
    '''
    Generator function to create a closure with the reference image and origin
    at the center of the reference image

    Returns a function f, which takes a query image and returns the accumulator
    '''
    referencePoint = (reference_image.shape[0]/2, reference_image.shape[1]/2)
    r_table = build_r_table(reference_image, referencePoint)

    def f(query_image):
        return accumulate_gradients(r_table, query_image)

    return f
```

I seem to be stuck on how this function works.  "f" does not seem to be called anywhere, and I'm not sure how the function knows what "query_image" is?  I'v tried various Googling to find tips on Inner Functions, Closures, and Factory Functions, for example [this](https://realpython.com/blog/python/inner-functions-what-are-they-good-for/) and some similar pages, but all the examples I can find are more simplified and therefore not much help.  Can anybody offer some direction?

Comment: This code __*returns* a function__. Are you sure that's what you want? I doubt that's something you'd want to do in C++.

Comment: @Rawing, I'm aware the function returns a function, and that is the part I'd like to factor out, so I can translate into C++

Comment: Remove the line `def f(query_image):`, remove `return f`, and give the function a 2nd parameter named `query_image`. That should be easy to translate.

Answer (score 0):

The code is just *returning* the function `f` as a whole thing. There's no need to "know what the argument is" -- `f` will know it at the time it is called. The classic example is this:

```
>>> def f(x):
...     def g(y):
...         return x + y
...     return g
... 
>>> f
<function f at 0x7f8500603ae8>
>>> f(1)
<function f.<locals>.g at 0x7f8500603a60>
>>> s = f(1)
>>> s(2)
3
```

Here, as in your function, `g` *closes over* another value (`x` or `r_table`, respectively), while still expecting its actual argument.

Since there is a closed-over value, you cannot directly factor out `f`. One traditional approach is to return an object containing the value, which has some kind of call method representing the function; the easier way in C++ nowadays is to use a lambda function:

```
int f(int x) {
  auto g = [x](int y) {
    return x + y
  };
  return g;
}
```

In C++ you have the "advantage" that it will yell at you if don't specify which values you are closing over (that's the `[x]` here). But internall, it does pretty much the same thing (constructing an anonymous class with an `x`-member).

Comment: If my C++ is ill-formed, please just edit it, I don't actually use C++ very often.

Answer (score 0):

C++ before C++11 does not have function as type.

You can use the following class to emulate the semantics (pseudo code):

```
class GeneralHoughClosure {
  public:
    GeneralHoughClosure(reference_image) {
      referencePoint = (reference_image.shape[0]/2, reference_image.shape[1]/2)
      r_table = build_r_table(reference_image, referencePoint)
    }
    void Run(queryImage) {
      return accumulate_gradients(r_table, query_image)
    }
    void operator()(queryImage) {
      return accumulate_gradients(r_table, query_image)
    }        
  }
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
gg = new GeneralHoughClosure(reference_image)
gg.Run(queryImage1)
gg(queryImage2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, is there a way I can factor out the nested function without adding a class?

Comment: C++11  does have functions as types. You can return an [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) initialized (for instance) with a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), just as you do in python.

Comment: You are right, I updated the answer. 
Some of us do not have the luxury to work with C++11 :-)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to translate to C++ without the use of a class, returning a std::function, or using lambdas, any suggestions on how to accomplish this?